# How to snap my mouse cursor to vertex for the first click?

Tags: snapping

I want to cut my model half.

How to snap my mouse cursor to vertex for the first click?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Bicest tool cannot snap (god knows why). It's currently a requested feature https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/gpfbbc/

Comment: That said, you can use *Knife project* instead ;)

Comment: Oh! thank you. I will try. Thank you so much